# Arduino connect to internet without ethernet shild

Tags: arduino, ethernet

I'm beginner on arduino, and I'd like know if there are some way to connect to internet without ethernet shield just using an arduino plugged on my computer using a usb cable?

Thnaks.

Comment: Well by the transitive law of connections: if your computer is connected to the internet and your arduino is connected to your computer...

Comment: As Nick says.  Can you be more specific about what you want to do?  You can have a program on the PC send and receive data between the PC and the Arduino via serial communications over the USB port, and the program (sketch) on the Arduino doing the same on the other end.  The program on your PC can access the internet and be a relay (and of course, much more).

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @David Tweed,  my idea is connect to internet to read tweets and control my arduino based oon this tweets. Unfortunately I don't have an internet child yet, so I'd like know if there are some way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

My solution, coming from a software developer by trade, would be to write a small program that would run on the computer and act as the middleman: translating messages sent by the Arduino,  fetching URLs and sending results back to the Arduino.  Overly complicated I'm sure.

Comment: If only a small set of operations are needed, this would keep the Arduino software simpler than trying to do a full IP stack for ppp within the narrow confines fo the ATMEGA's 2K ram - though that has been done of course.

Answer (score 0):

Your Arduino would not be directly connected to the internet.
It would be connect to your pc like a I/O card and the pc would be connected to the internet, and to use the Arduino as a I/O card is quite common.

If you feel that a PC is a little bit expensive, you can look into those guys that connects Arduino to a Raspberry PI with just this intention.

Comment: Of course your pc isn't directly connected to the Internet's major peering points either.  It's all done by passing traffic to others.  With a ppp connection such that the Arduino is sending and receiving IP traffic, there is little fundamental difference - the Internet has a diversity of physical layers, 10/100 ethernet being of little unique importance beyond incumbency in the last hundred feet, and today consumer connections are increasingly behind carrier-grade NAT, in addition to any NAT done by your personal modem/firewall/router/access point.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a PPP link over the serial port: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-point_protocol , although I'm not sure how to get Windows to proxy the internet connection to a PPP connection. It's definitely possible in Linux.